# c# PLinq AsParallel Select hangs

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, parallel-processing

I want to process a large ammount of data stored in a text file. Here is the code I use to make it work faster:

```
var result = File
   .ReadLines(textBox1.Text)
   .AsParallel()
   .WithDegreeOfParallelism(100)
   .Select(line => ProcessLine(line));
```

The method `ProcessLine` gets the line then processes it and add it to an `ArrayList`.

After all the processing is done I load the `ArrayList` into a Datagrid,
but sometimes it completes all the lines and sometimes it hangs, I don't know why.

Any suggestions ?

**Update**
 Here is the Method ProcessLine

```
private string  ProcessLine(string domain)
        {



            ProcessStartInfo cmdinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            cmdinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            cmdinfo.Arguments = "/c nslookup";
            cmdinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            cmdinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            cmdinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            cmdinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            cmdinfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            Process cmdd = new Process();
            cmdd = Process.Start(cmdinfo);
            string spf = "none";
        createproc:
            try
            {



                cmdd.StandardInput.WriteLine("set q=txt");
                cmdd.StandardInput.Flush();
                cmdd.StandardInput.WriteLine(domain);

                cmdd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                cmdd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
                StreamReader r = cmdd.StandardOutput;

                //cmdd.WaitForExit();
                cmdd.Close();
                spf = "";
                string rdl = string.Empty;
                bool spffound = false;
                while (rdl != null)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        rdl = r.ReadLine();

                        if (rdl.Contains("v=spf"))
                        {
                            spffound = true;
                            spf = rdl.Trim();
                            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                            {
                                textBox2.AppendText("domain found : " + domain + Environment.NewLine + "SPF = " + spf + Environment.NewLine);
                                textBox2.Update();

                            }));
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                    }
                }
                if (!spffound)
                    spf = "none";

                nbrDoms++;
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    DomsElapsed.Text = nbrDoms + " Domains Elapsed";
                    DomsElapsed.Update();

                }));
                SPFRecord srx = new SPFRecord((string)spf.Clone(), (string)domain.Clone());

                if (srx == null)
                {
                    cmdd.Kill();
                    cmdinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                    cmdinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                    cmdinfo.Arguments = "/c nslookup";
                    cmdinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                    cmdinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                    cmdinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    cmdinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    cmdinfo.RedirectStandardError = false;

                    cmdd = new Process();
                    cmdd.StartInfo = cmdinfo;
                    cmdd.Start();

                    goto createproc;
                }

                lock (pageManager)
                {
                    pageManager.AddRecord(srx);
                }
                //this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                //{
                //}));

            }
            catch(Exception exc)
            {
                cmd.Kill();

                cmdinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                cmdinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                cmdinfo.Arguments = "/c nslookup";
                cmdinfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                cmdinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                cmdinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                cmdinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                cmdinfo.RedirectStandardError = false;

                cmdd = new Process();
                cmdd.StartInfo = cmdinfo;
                cmdd.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                goto createproc;
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the code in `ProcessLine` method? I suspect a race condition there.

Comment: @RePierre take a look at the update

Comment: Can you remove `WithDegreeOfParallelism(100)`, this is strange level parallelism expected, let it work on default

Comment: when i use WithDegreeOfParallelism(100) it works fine sometimes
when i use WithDegreeOfParallelism(1) it works fine always but i need speed :(

Comment: and yeah removed WithDegreeOfParallelism still not working

Answer (score 0):

Read the lines of text into a string, with something like file.readalllines(psudo code)

Basically each thread is locking the other, are you trying this for speed or because the file is too large to fit into memory?

Comment: How did you guess that threads are locking each other, nothing available in the original question

Comment: I'm trying this for speed cause i have like +15000000 records
i process each recod then add it to the pagemanager the page manager creates an empty page (ArrayList)  if there is no pages then it ads the record.if the page count == 27 pagemanager creates another page then keep adding records  after the process end i load each page on a datagrid when user click next it loads from the selected page and show it on datagrid

Comment: Mrinal Kamboj - I assumed locking after reading the code. And the reason I asked about loading into memory is the fact that there are multiple threads all trying to read from a text file, which is a waste of time.  I would read it all in one string, THEN thread.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things to mention:

1. *Do not use* `goto` statements - it's hard to understand what your method does. Just move the creation of the `Process` into a separate method and call that method instead of using `goto`
2. Processes *do take time to load* and quite a lot for what you want to do. To avoid this load penalty, instead of creating and calling a process try to replace that with a method which does the same. There's an [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-nslookup-implementation-in-C-Sharp/) of `nslookup` without calling the process. Try adapting it to your needs
3. **Remove the `lock`s** - if your application somehow gets to use 100 threads the `lock` is a waste of time. You'll have 99 threads *waiting* for the other *single* thread to push its data to the `pageManager`. As @Mrinal Kamboj pointed out, you can use a thread-safe collection. In this case, use a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) and add the results there. At the other end of the queue have the `pageManager` listening and consuming each item as it arrives.
4. The UI needs its separate cycles to refresh which *also takes time*. If `pageManager.AddRecord()` somehow has to refresh the UI then the other threads won't wait just for the add operation.
5. UI updates must be done in the thread that created the controls and that thread *can't update the UI if it's waiting for another thread*.

The overall algorithm should look like this:

```
public class Engine
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<string> _messagePipeline = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    public BlockingCollection<string> MessagePipeline
    {
        get { return _messagePipeline; }
    }

    public void Process(string file)
    {
        File.ReadLines(file)
            .AsParallel()
            .ForAll(line =>
            {
                var nsLookupResult = NsLookupMethod(line);
                if(nsLookupResult.HasInfoYouNeed)
                    _messagePipeline.Add(nsLookupResult.DisplayInfo);
            });
    }
}

public class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly Engine _engine; // ...

    private void OnStartButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _engine.Process(textbox1.Text);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
        {
            foreach(var message in _engine.MessagePipeline.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                // show the message
                Application.DoEvents(); // allow the app to process other events not just pushing messages.
            }
        }, cts.Token,
        TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness,
        // Specify that you want UI updates to be done on the UI thread
        // and not on any other thread
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

And that should do it. I do have a (more or less academic) [example](https://github.com/RePierre/dot-net-async/tree/master/BruteForce) of this kind of logic in action. The UI update logic is in the [MainForm](https://github.com/RePierre/dot-net-async/blob/master/BruteForce/Client/Forms/MainForm.cs) of the application and the processing logic is in an [Engine class](https://github.com/RePierre/dot-net-async/blob/master/BruteForce/Client/Core/HackerEngine.cs); have a look there.